# Fatal error which fetching data from mysqli with limit

Tags: php, database, mysqli, fetch

Set pagination, on `$result1` are fetching all rows from table and, `$new_result` set its LIMIT.
But i got an error "Fatal error: Call to a member `function fetch_assoc()` on a non-object in `/home/`...."

```
$page_limit = 28;
$table_name_3 = 'table';

if (!isset($_GET['page']) )
    { $start=0; } else
    { $start = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $page_limit; }

$mysqli = new mysqli("xxxxxxx" , "xxxxxxx" , "xxxxxxx" , "xxxxxxxxx");
$result1 = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM $table_name_3 
                 WHERE `categories` LIKE  '$newq'
                 AND   `inStock` LIKE 'true' ");
while ( $rows =  $result1->fetch_assoc() ) {

$new_result = $mysqli->query( $rows . "LIMIT $start,$page_limit " );
while ( $rows =  $new_result->fetch_assoc() ) {

$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$store = $rows['store'];
$productId = $rows['productId'];
```

Comment: you cant do that, your concatenating the array with a string, bdway im not the one who downvote it

Comment: Check your db connection is working

Comment: Do not use while inside while loop

Comment: add `or die($mysqli->error)` behind yoyr mysqli->query and let us know what is the exact error that you get

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to do it, as your `$rows` object contains an array of fetched results -> `$row['columnname']`, `$row['columnname2']` and so on. Instead, use it in one query :

```
"SELECT * FROM $table_name_3 WHERE `categories` LIKE  '$newq' 
                            AND `inStock` LIKE 'true' 
                            LIMIT ($page_limit-$offset) OFFSET $offset"
```

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't make much sense, I don't understand why two requests and I don't understand the 2nd request at all, have you tried with one request?

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name_3
 WHERE 
`categories` LIKE  '$newq' 
 AND `inStock` LIKE 'true' 
 LIMIT $start,$page_limit
```

Comment: i am doing pagination, in this pagination first i fetched all data then second  i will set limit as per page number.

Comment: Thats not how it works, you don't need to do it on 2 separate requests, set the limit on the 1st request